# How to define a 80-bit size variable

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

I need to declare a 80bit size variable in C program compiled by gcc (I need it to pass data to asm procedure which works on fpu, which is called by this program written in C)
My architecture is AMD x64
I tried `long double`, `__float80`, but for them `sizeof` returns 12 instead of `10`.
So how to declare such variable?

Comment: 80-bit numbers are used in FPU registers, not in CPU registers

Comment: Consider `char c[10];`

Comment: How are you passing the the variable to the assembly procedure? If you're passing as an argument in a function call your assembly procedure will need to follow your C compiler's calling convention.

Comment: Ross Ridge, so if my C compiler ( gcc ) treat long double as 96 bit, and I am passing to asm procedure pointer to array of long double, how can I use it in this asm procedure? there are opcodes like qword ( 64bit) tword (80bit) oword (128bit) but there isn't any for 96bit. For example I need to pass result from fpu to memory pointed by ebx: **fstp tword [ebx]**, but tword means **80bit**, but C compiler created it as 96bit.

Answer (score 4):

The size includes padding for alignment, it is nevertheless a 80 bit value. The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-m96bit-long-double-2671) says:

> -m96bit-long-double
>
> -m128bit-long-double
>
> These switches control the size of long double type. The x86-32 application binary interface specifies the size to be 96 bits, so
>   -m96bit-long-double is the default in 32-bit mode.
>
> Modern architectures (Pentium and newer) prefer long double to be aligned to an 8- or 16-byte boundary. In arrays or structures conforming to the ABI, this is not possible. So specifying -m128bit-long-double aligns long double to a 16-byte boundary by padding the long double with an additional 32-bit zero.
>
> In the x86-64 compiler, -m128bit-long-double is the default choice as its ABI specifies that long double is aligned on 16-byte boundary.
>
> Notice that neither of these options enable any extra precision over the x87 standard of 80 bits for a long double.
>
> Warning: if you override the default value for your target ABI, this changes the size of structures and arrays containing long double variables, as well as modifying the function calling convention for functions taking long double. Hence they are not binary-compatible with code compiled without that switch.
>
> -mlong-double-64
>
> -mlong-double-80
>
> -mlong-double-128
>
> These switches control the size of long double type. A size of 64 bits makes the long double type equivalent to the double type. This is the default for 32-bit Bionic C library. A size of 128 bits makes the long double type equivalent to the __float128 type. This is the default for 64-bit Bionic C library.
>
> Warning: if you override the default value for your target ABI, this changes the size of structures and arrays containing long double variables, as well as modifying the function calling convention for functions taking long double. Hence they are not binary-compatible with code compiled without that switch.